# Xcode 11 - no iOS 13.1.2 simulator (just 13.0)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have installed Xcode 11, needing the ios 13 simulator, but as I see I have available ios 13.0, not 13.1.2 (as installed on physical iphones). The issue is that my app has a lot of strange UI behavior (strange offset for views placed unde the navigation bar, round images with shadows not working correctly etc).

Is there a way to use the ios 13.1.2 simulator in Xcode for now?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: With Xcode **11.1 GM Seed**, you can use iOS 13.1 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 11.2 includes the iOS 13.2 simulator runtime.

iOS 13.0 and 13.1 simulators will not be offered for download so you should not expect to see them in the downloadable simulators list even in Xcode 11.2.

There are many important bug fixes in both Xcode 11.2 and iOS 13.2. I recommend all developers and all users upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check below link of release note by apple might come new simulator ios 13.1 on word
there is beta version but you can test or debug

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_3_beta_release_notes/

https://developer.apple.com/download/